# (JavaScript) data.split('\n') is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems

I am trying to make a random string picker with a text document that splits at every line.

However, when I try to run it, it says that `data.split` is not a function.

```
fs.readFile('list.txt', function(err, data){
        if(err) throw err;
        var lines = data.split('\n');
        var rand = [Math.floor(Math.random()*lines.length)];
        var rlist = lines[rand]
})
```

Comment: Try with `fs.readFile('list.txt', 'utf8', ...)`

Comment: @miparnisari That worked! Thank you for the help! I actually only started coding in JS about 3-4 days ago :P

Comment: Cool. Please select my answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_file_options_callback):

> The callback is passed two arguments (err, data), where `data` is the
>   contents of the file. **If no encoding is specified, then the raw buffer is returned.**

A raw buffer is just an array, and JavaScript [arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) don't have the `split` function. So you need to specify an `encoding` to get the text result.

```
fs.readFile('list.txt', 'utf8', ...)
```